# Dynamically adding additional bars to bar chart in SQL report builder

Tags: sql, dynamic, reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to create a bar chart in Report Builder 3.0 with multiple series. The stored procedure for it uses a dynamic pivot and outputs additional columns if more series are added to the data. I'd like these additional columns to appear as additional sets of bars in my chart, but I'm unsure of how to approach this problem and haven't had much success googling for an answer.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS does not like datasets where the columns change. It relies on a fixed structure.

The way to approach this is to NOT pivot your data but let SSRS aggregate it in the chart. *If you also need a pivoted table of data then just use a standard matrix control and that will do the job for you.*

As an example I created a test data set like this.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (SeriesName varchar(10), CategoryName varchar(10), DateYear int, Amount int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Fruit', 'Apple', 2015, 10),
('Fruit', 'Apple', 2016, 12),
('Fruit', 'Apple', 2017, 14),
('Fruit', 'Orange', 2015, 8),
('Fruit', 'Orange', 2016, 10),
('Fruit', 'Orange', 2017, 12),
('Vegetable', 'Carrot', 2015, 7),
('Vegetable', 'Carrot', 2016, 6),
('Vegetable', 'Carrot', 2017, 5),
('Vegetable', 'Lettuce', 2015, 15),
('Vegetable', 'Lettuce', 2016, 14),
('Vegetable', 'Lettuce', 2017, 13)

select * from @t
```

Then a just created a simple column chart with `DateYear` and `SeriesName` as the Series groups and `CategoryName` as the Category Group. Then added `Amount` as Values.

The design looks like this...
[image]

And the output looks like this,

[image]

This may not be exactly what you need but hopefully will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a tonne for your response. I was really over complicating things, this solved my problem.